# List vs Df difference within lapply bulk download

Tags: r, dataframe

I was using this function below to bulk load several data txt files. Before deciding to subset within the lapply, my loaded frames were loaded as a list in RStudio. It was transformed into a df using the do call.

I decided to add two essential subset arguments within the function to remove empty columns. Without the final do.call, df first became a data frame, not a list. Albeit it still loads in correctly for do call, I am wondering what the main difference is with lists and df, specifically with regards to this situation.

```
df <- lapply(temp, function(x) {
dfs<- read.table(x,
               header=TRUE,
               fill=TRUE,
               na.strings= "N/A",
               sep="\t",
               stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

#Added, then changed type of df before do.call
  dfs<- dfs[!dfs$Variable %in% "",]
  dfs<- dfs[!dfs$X5TH %in% "",]
#

  dfs<- cbind(codes, dfs)

return(dfs)
 })
CR13distr<- do.call("rbind", df)
remove(df)
```

I have checked the results, and they seem to be identical outputs (except the removal of empty rows). However, to be sure, does that intermediate change from list to df change anything significant?

Comment: Data frames are lists. They are a particular subset of lists where every element is of the same length. `df` will be a list of data.frames here no matter what, even if there's only one (or 0!) data.frames.

Comment: I would also add I think you have a mistake (that won't result in an error) with `!dfs$Variable %in% "",` - both those lines instead should be `!all(dfs$Variable == "")`

Comment: @SeñorO Thanks I see now. Is there a benefit having lists rbind vs data.frames rbind? Is  !all(dfs$Variable == "") better than !dfs$Variable %in% "", ?